# Powershell issues with Start-Process of same script elevated

Tags: powershell, elevated-privileges

I have a script that inventories the installed software on a machine, based on certain criteria provided in arguments. It also needs to support being buried in a very deep folder structure (Architects just think like that and I need to support it, not control it). And since it now also supports AppX, which requires running elevated, which in turn requires the full path to the PS1 in the -file argument, I am running into issues with the overall length of the `Target` value in the shortcut.
So, I was looking at the usual run with the -verb argument approach, like this

```
If (-not ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) {   
    $psArguments = @('-nologo', '-noExit', '-executionpolicy', 'bypass', '-verb', 'Runas', '-file',$PSCommandPath)
    $pxArguments = @($myInvocation.BoundParameters.GetEnumerator().ForEach({"-$($_.Key)", "$($_.Value)"}))
    $arguments = $psArguments + $pxArguments
    
    Start-Process 'powershell.exe' -ArgumentList:$arguments -Verb:Runas
    Stop-Process $PID
} else {
    Write-Host 'Elevated'
    # actual code to process
}
```

But I am having two issues there, one is critical, one less so.
On the critical side, I see a second blue PowerShell console open for a split second, but then it closes with no error or anything. I would have expected the -noExit argument in `$psArguments` to at least leave that window open for me, so I could read any errors. But I can't see any red, so that makes me think there is no error, and this usually happens when the `-file` argument doesn't point to an actual script. However, if I validate the arguments like so

```
foreach ($item in $arguments) {
    Write-Host "$item"
}
Write-Host "$PSCommandPath $(Test-Path $PSCommandPath)"
```

The arguments all look good and Test-Path returns true.
So, what in this am I getting wrong, such that I don't get a new PowerShell console that actually works?

The second issue is that I have defined fonts and colors and console size in the shortcut, and I wonder if there is a single variable, perhaps `$host`, that I could then send to the second session populated with the values of the first. I suspect not, because I think the only types that can be used as arguments are strings and numbers.

DOH: I was on the right track, with that comment about it looking like the script wasn't found. There are SPACES in that path, so I need

```
$psArguments = @('-nologo', '-noExit', '-executionpolicy', 'bypass', '-file',"`"$PSCommandPath`"")
```

Now I just need to deal with resizing the console. I can live without fonts and colors, but the width and text wrapping I need to address.

Comment: In regards to your powershell window question: take a look at the parameters:

    ```-windowstyle```
    ```-noNewWindow``` 

of the `start-process` cmdlet, the reason why the window disappears immediatly is probably related to the missing parameter `-wait`.

Comment: In this case I don't want to wait, because I am actually going to kill the calling session. I should explore window styles a bit more anyway, but the big issue was that I wasn't wrapping my path in quotes, and since the path had spaces that was truncating the path, so it wasn't found, so it was instantly failing with no error because there was no script found to generate the error.

Comment: yes probably, so with the -wait parameter you should have been able to see what has happened. anyways you got it fixed...